# Ninja Error while building Chrome Test Shell APK

Tags: python, google-chrome, ninja

I am building the Chrome 32 Test Shell build on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. I get the following error;

```
GYP_GENERATORS set to 'ninja'
Updating projects from gyp files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ajithk/Android_Browser/SBROWSER-TRUNK/src/build/gyp_chromium", line 157, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.main(args))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gyp/__init__.py", line 445, in main
    options.circular_check)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gyp/__init__.py", line 55, in Load
    generator = __import__(generator_name, globals(), locals(), generator_name)
ImportError: No module named ninja

ninja: Entering directory `out/Release'
ninja: fatal: chdir to 'out/Release' - No such file or directory

If anyone of you faced the similar issues, please share the soluion

Thanks,
Ajith
```

Comment: Do you find solution for this ?